# Jquery html? what the heck?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this should be pretty basic, but from my understanding, JQuery's html() function should be pretty much the same as as the javascript innterHTML function?
If so I'm not finding this at all in my testing.
My intention is to to replace the html content between the tr open/close which I've

html:

```
<table>
  <tr id="task:1234">
    <td>
      <button id="abutton" type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="abutton1" type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="abutton2" type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="abutton3" type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#abutton").click(function() {
    var newtddata = "<td><button id=\"abutton\" type=\"button\">I've been clicked!</button></td>";
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    //$("#task:1234").html(newtddata);
    document.getElementById("task:1234").innerHTML = newtddata;
  });
});
```

so, as the script is written, this works... the innerHTML of the task:1234 id tr get's replaced with the newtddata variable string. But trying it with the JQuery html() function, nothing. Should I be using replaceWith ? if so, how do I specify to target replaceWith to the innerHTML of the tr, and not the tr itself?

Sorry if this is obvious, JavaScript isn't exactly my first language and I need to get my arms around this in short order.

Comment: show us the jQuery version.

Comment: You should read this http://api.jquery.com/html

Comment: DA... the commented out line in my script IS the JQuery version (?)

Comment: read this:https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `jQuery`doesn't 'like' the `:` colon in your `id` tag, something that you should avoid doing anyway.  Change the tag to something else, or escape it

```
$('#task\\:1234')
```

Comment: ack... I've inherited this code so I'll have to deal with the colon notation. But this fixed it. Thanks Eric.

Answer (score 3):

`JQuery` uses `CSS` syntax for selecting elements, some characters are interpreted as CSS notation.

For example, ID attributes, after an initial letter `(a-z or A-Z)`, may also use periods and colons, in addition to letters, numbers, hyphens, and underscores. The colon `(":")` and period `(".")` are problematic within the context of a `JQuery` selector because they indicate a pseudo-class and class, respectively.

In order to tell `JQuery` to treat these characters literally rather than as `CSS` notation, they must be `escaped` by placing `two backslashes` in front of them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#abutton").click(function() {
    var newtddata = "<td><button id=\"abutton\" type=\"button\">I've been clicked!</button></td>";
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    $(modifyMe("#task:1234")).html(newtddata);
    //document.getElementById("task:1234").innerHTML = newtddata;
  });
});

function modifyMe( myid ) {
    return myid.replace( /(:|\.|\[|\]|,)/g, "\\$1" ); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="task:1234">
    <td>
      <button id="abutton" type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="abutton1" type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="abutton2" type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="abutton3" type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```